# jQuery difference between argument and parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

I have jQuery code block as follows;

```
(function($){
  //Normal code goes here
})(jQuery);
```

Now I wanted to understand

1. If this is a self-executing function ? If yes, why ?
2. What is the difference between the "$" passed to the function and "jQuery" specified at the end ? Is one of them called an argument and the other parameter ?
3. Is it necessary to specify the "jQuery" at the end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> If this is a self-executing function ? If yes, why ?

Yes and no. It is an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), but some people tend to call these "self-executing" even though this is usually associated with the idea of recursion.

> What is the difference between the "$" passed to the function and "jQuery" specified at the end ? Is one of them called an argument and the other parameter ?

Exactly.

> Is it necessary to specify the "jQuery" at the end.

Otherwise from where the `$` parameter would be populated?

---

I'll add one more question which you seem have to have missed:

> Why use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression?

It simply aliases `jQuery` to `$` inside the IIFE scope so you can safely use `$` independently of jQuery being in [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode or not. Very useful for developing plugins and working with WP.

Comment: "*Otherwise from where the $ argument would be populated?*". While I agree the difference between `$` and `jquery` is that between an argument and a parameter, I'd call `$` the parameter and `jquery` the argument.

Comment: @Bruno My bad, just got up. You're right - `jQuery` enter the function as formal parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's "self executing".  The inner part is a "function expression" and the (necessary) parameters `(jQuery)` then cause it to be immediately invoked, hence the more usual term of "immediately invoked function expression".

The variable `$` is local in scope to the function.  jQuery plugins are often written this way so that the common `$` abbreviation may be used internally even if jQuery is in "no-conflict" mode, because the (global) `$` variable is being used by something else.

Formally the variables in the declaration are called the "parameters" and the ones in the invocation are the "arguments".  I think in JS the ambiguity arises because you can access the supplied parameters using the `arguments` pseudo array.

Answer (score 0):

1) Self-Executing and Immediately-Executing

You can tell because it's got the parens at the end.

You write a function like this:

```
function myFunc () {}
```

or like

```
var myFunc = function () {};
```

And you call a function like:

```
myFunc();
```

You have it written as `(function () {})();` so it fires as soon as it hits the end.

2) Parameters are what a function expects.
Arguments are what you give a function.

```
var number_arg = 35,
    string_arg = "Bob";

function myFunc (number_param, string_param) {
    console.log(number_param, string_param);
}

myFunc(number_arg, string_arg); // 35 "Bob";
```

The fact that params can be named differently from arguments means that you can "alias" values differently inside of functions.

```
function myFunc ($) { console.log($); }

myFunc("SUPERLONGSTRINGOFDOOMISWHATI'MPUTTINGINHERE");

myFunc(MYAPP.Module.sub_module.plug_in);
```

Meanwhile, inside the function, all of these things can be worked with, just using `$`.

3) "Aliasing" is what's going on with the `jQuery` versus `$`.